# Schedule a transaction without making a deposit

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

Is it possible in solidity to schedule a transaction without making a deposit and without specifying the amount? As far as I know with the Ethereum Alarm Clock you need to deposit the ethereum and the gas that you want to transact into the address of the contract.
For example would it be possible to schedule the transfer of the 50% of my future address balance to xxx in one year.

In the case that its not possible would it be if the amount to transfer is specified but not deposited, for example transfer 10 eth to yyy in 6 months.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the basic entities of the public Ethereum - ether and gas, any payments on debt are impossible - you must always have enough funds on the account that generates the transaction for value + gas on moment.

For derived entities - tokens, schemes of any complexity are possible, including payments on credit, with a deferral, and so on, but this is determined by the implementation of a particular token.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum network does not allow scheduling of transactions natively. You can workaround this limitation with [Ethereum Alarm Clock](https://ethereum-alarm-clock-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#what-problem-does-this-solve) though.